# How to use 2 trampolines in parallel - rxjava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

context: android, rxjava2

Hello,
Trampoline Scheduler is very useful for my use case, how can I have 2 trampolines in parallel ? I will use one to handle incoming sequential input data and one for other things to avoid collisons. Thanks.

Comment: Trampolines are means to make sure one thread is servicing a work queue at a time. You'd need separate threads so they can progress independently. You could use two workers of a `Schedulers.newThread` for this purpose.

Comment: Schedulers.newThread with create a new thread each time, that will take a lot of memory. The design of Trampoline is best for my use case, but I want 2 trampolines to handle 2 different types of task. One type of task is to handle a hundred of events each second.

Comment: What is the code you are trying to parallelize? Trampolines are mainly used to remove concurrency and parallelism in tests and make them run on the current test thread. They are not there to introduce concurrency or parallelism. If you are worried about excessive thread creation, create two separate single schedulers via the [plugins](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/plugins/RxJavaPlugins.html#createSingleScheduler-java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory-).

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution in the comment of Akarnokd :

What is the code you are trying to parallelize? Trampolines are mainly used to remove concurrency and parallelism in tests and make them run on the current test thread. They are not there to introduce concurrency or parallelism. If you are worried about excessive thread creation, create two separate single schedulers via the plugins. – akarnokd